# Task Adobe Flash Player Updater creates network slowness?

Tags: networking, services, windows-task-scheduler, flash-player

Does the task "Adobe Flash Player Updater"   ( this task gets in the PC when Flash player is installed and runs by default each hour  Task Scheduler  C:\Winnt\Tasks).
might be the cause of local network slowness?

The service linked to this task is the "Adobe Flash Player Update Service" and it is in Manual status.  Is this task doing really something?  to do something the service shouldn't be in "automatic" status?

I am trying to avoid to delete the task, delete the task is simple but it will be created again if I installed a new version of Flash.

Please any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to delete the task. Try simply disabling the task instead of outright deleting it. If the problem clears up, then it is indeed the updater. In that case, you can leave it disabled and periodically enable it to check for updates or manually [check for](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) and [install](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) updates.

If the problem remains, then it might not be the updater itself but a newer version of Flash which includes [P2P functionality](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) to [share your bandwidth](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help08.html#117846). See if [disabling it](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager09.html) fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you Synetech, I forgot to mention the machines are Win XP. I tried to disable the task, but that feature is not available in WinXP  , I tried schtasks /change /tn TaskName /disable  but the syntaxis is not available for WinXP.  The updates are managed through a central tool, so that's why I thought that deleting the task was not a big issue. After deleting the task I am able to launch websites that require Flash, am I overlooking something if I go to the deletion of the task?

Comment: @fl0w3rl, you should be able to disable a task in XP. Is there a reason you *must* use the command-line? If not, then just open the *Control Panel*, select *Scheduled Tasks*, open the *Properties* dialog for the updater, and un-check the [`Enabled` checkbox at the bottom](http://www.notageek.it/wp-content/images/ntfs_stuff/ntfsStuff_scheduled_Job.png). And no, there’s no reason that you can’t delete the task altogether and perform manual updates; that’s exactly what I do (for *everything* because I don’t trust developers enough to do automatic updates).

Comment: Thanks Synetech, yes unfortunately the only way I can use is through command line. The weird thing is that by default the task is set to run the Flash Player Update Service (C:\WINNT\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerUpdateService.exe) each hour, but if I check the .exe  the last day appearing as modyfied is the same day I did the upgrade (month ago).  Honestly, I don't think this task is doing anything, I have looked for Adobe Documentation but haven't found info about this yet, I keep looking....